# Java loops and zero divisor

Tags: java

I am creating a program that will calculate two numbers. My issue is  0 will be an illegal input to the program but instead of asking again for two numbers.

The program continues to run without giving an error, or giving any answer when ZERO is imputed, it's suppose to ask the user to input two different numbers again.

I've done all the code and it mostly works and there is no visible error.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner.*;

public class MinilabLoopLogic
{
    public static void main(String[ ] args)
    {    
        int num1, num2, divisor, total;

        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);  //you do it!

        System.out.print("Please enter 2 integers (separated by spaces): ");
        num1 = kb.nextInt();
        num2 = kb.nextInt();

        System.out.println("\n\nThis program will generate numbers BETWEEN "+ num1 + " " + num2);

        System.out.println("\nPlease enter the integer your output should be divisible by: ");
        divisor = kb.nextInt();
        while (divisor == 0)
        {
            divisor = kb.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("\n\n----------------------------------------");
        //Be able to handle 1st number smaller 
        //   OR 2nd number smalle
        //Use the modulus operator to check if a number is divisible 
        if (num1 < num2)
        {
            for (total = num1+1; total < num2; total++ )
            {
                if (total % divisor == 0)
                { 
                    System.out.println(total);
                }
            }  
        }
        else
        {            
            for (total = num1 - 1; total > num2; total--)
            {
                if (total % divisor == 0)
                {
                    System.out.println(total);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}//end main()
```

Comment: Whats the question?
Could you expand on runs for ever part?

Comment: I couldn't see a problem just examining the code so I ran it, and it works fine for me. If I enter a zero divisor, it waits for me to enter a new number, and once I enter a non-zero number, it gives me the results and exits.

Comment: Code might be a heck of a lot easier to read if you fix (align) all the indentations.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't want to get into style issues, but that's particularly bad indentation. Good indentation makes the code more readable, both for others, and for you when you go back to it in a year and have no idea what it does. :-)

Comment: Good start on indent fixing. Now do the rest, e.g. is the first `if (total % divisor == 0)` inside or outside of the `for` loop? Inside, of course, but indentation would seem to say otherwise.

Comment: I have edited it some more, with some of the indention suggestions, Also I added the suggested part.

Comment: I'm rolling back the edit. The correct code should be in the answer, while the wrong code should be in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies in your while loop looking for the divisor:

```
       System.out.println("\nPlease enter the integer your output should be divisible by: ");
            divisor = kb.nextInt();  // gets your divisor
            while (divisor == 0)  //if it is illegal, e.g. 0
            {
                divisor = kb.nextInt(); // waits for more divisor input
            }
```

You should output a string to tell the user what the problem is. say:

```
            divisor = kb.nextInt();  // gets your divisor
            while (divisor == 0)  //if it is illegal, e.g. 0
            {
                System.out.println("\nYou can't divide by 0. Try again!: ");
                divisor = kb.nextInt(); // waits for more divisor input
            }
```

Also, if you want them to have to re-enter the `num1` and `num2` then scanner input has to happen in that while loop.

Comment: His code looks perfectly fine! there is no problem. what did you change?

Comment: Hmm, how is user supposed to know to enter a divisor, when you remove the prompt text?

Comment: No prompt, really? geesh. s/Try again!/Whatever floats your boat/

Comment: I see where my mistake was, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You added the following in an edit:

> The program continues to run without giving an error, or giving any answer when ZERO is imputed, it's suppose to ask the user to input two different numbers again.

That is because you just loop back to get another value when a zero is entered, *without* writing any new prompt text.

It also only gets a new divisor number, not "two different numbers". If you looped back to before "Please enter 2 integers", it'd actually end up prompting for all 3 numbers again.